# When should you use a script loader?

Tags: javascript, performance

e.g. lab.js, yepnope.js, require.js

I'm a little fuzzy on at what point it's advantageous to use a script loader. I know that when you have significant browser, or feature targeted js, it can be good. But there's performance tradeoffs for making extra requests versus just concatenating scripts together, both in terms of UI responsiveness and page load time. And then there's optimizing for caching to worry about as well.

I have a feeling I'm going to get a lot of "It depends" answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a good refection on script loaders

[How, When, And Why Script Loaders Are Appropriate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/scriptjunkie/hh227261.aspx)